# Selected column in For Loop ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, for-loop

I have a following function in a controller. It is called from `index.cshtml`. `var relays` works fine and I got the `replays.count()`. `PRESETDETAILS` has some columns from which I want to access specific columns in a loop (like I have mentioned in `response.write`).

Kindly tell me how I can get the specific columns in the for loop.

```
    #region "Apply Preset Handlers"
    public ActionResult btnApply_Click(int? id)
    {
        var relays = db.PRESETDETAILS.ToList().Where(t => (t.PRESETID).Equals(id));
        for (int k = 0; k < relays.Count(); k++)
        {
            Response.Write(relays.Select(s => new relays{PRESETDETAILID = s.PRESETDETAILID }).ToString());   

        }
        return View("Index");
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to loop through them, you're simply select the same things over and over...

```
var relays = db.PRESETDETAILS.Where(t => t.PRESETID == id).ToList();
foreach (var replay in replays)
{
    Response.Write(string.Format("{0}", relay.ID));   
}
```

---

NOW... looking at your code:

- always use `ToList()` at the end of the query;
- `ToList()` actually makes the call to the database, until then, it's just a promise
- Don't use `Response.Write` in your Controller, send the data to the View instead

your code should be:

```
public ActionResult btnApply_Click(int? id)
{
    var model = db.PRESETDETAILS.Where(t => t.PRESETID == id).ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

in your View you can loop through the records

```
@model List<YOUR_CLASS>

<ul>
    @foreach(var replay in Model)
    {
        <li>@replay.ID</li>
    }
</ul>
```

---

I can see that some MVC conventions are not yet in place with you, and I know it can be somewhat overwhelm from someone that comes from WebForms or a linear code approach, but why don't you take some time and check the FREE available course about ASP.MVC in the ASP.NET Website?

See the videos in the right side of this page: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will change the code accordingly. can you please explain what is "{0}".

Comment: @kaka `"{0}"` will be replaced by the first property after `,` means by `relay.ID` [More reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)